# EntityFramework Core 3 and Automapper. Include with Filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm trying to do an automapper ProjectTo<> call from an IQueryable using EFC3.
My objects has some navigation properties that I need to retrieve as such but others which I need to filter with a Where clause.

- I can achieve it doing 3 database calls

  ```
          var dto = _context.Bonds.Where(x => x.Id == request.Id).
              ProjectTo<BondDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider) // Mapping is done here
              .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken); 

          var price = _context.MarketDatas.OfType<RatingMarketData>()
              .Where(x => x.Date == request.Date && x.AssetId == request.Id)
              .ProjectTo<RatingMarketDataDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
              .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

          var rating = ... same than for price
  ```
- 1 database call with alot of Includes and mapping which I don't like

  ```
            var vm = _context.Bonds
              .Include(x => x.CallSchedule)
              .Include(x => x.PutSchedule)
              .Include(x => x.FixedCouponSchedule)
              .Include(x => x.FloatingCouponSchedule)
              .Include(x => x.RedemptionSchedule) // If I don't Include I don't get nested objects like ProjectTo<>
              .Where(x => x.Id == request.Id)
              .Select(b => new BondVm
              {
                  BondDto = _mapper.Map<BondDto>(b),

                  RatingDto = _mapper.Map<RatingMarketDataDto>(b.MarketDatas.OfType<RatingMarketData>()
                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.AssetId == request.Id && x.Date <= request.Date)),

                  PriceDto = _mapper.Map<PriceMarketDataDto>(
                      b.MarketDatas.OfType<PriceMarketData>()
                      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Date == request.Date && x.AssetId == request.Id))
              })
              .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
  ```
- 1 database call without using Automapper. Alot of manual mapping and ugly code. This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve but I would like to use the power of Automapper projectTo<<>>.

  ```
          var vm = await _context.Bonds
              .Where(b => b.Id == request.Id)
              .Select(bond => new
              {
                  Bond = new BondDto
                  {
                      Id = bond.Id.ToString(),
                      Currency = bond.Currency,
                      BorrowerClass = bond.BondSector.BorrowerClass,
                      CouponFrequency = bond.CouponFrequency,
                      AccruedDayCount = bond.AccruedDayCount,
                      CallScheduleStyle = bond.CallScheduleStyle,
                      CorrelatedResidual = bond.CorrelatedResidual,
                      IsPerpetual = bond.IsPerpetual,
                      Issuer = bond.Issuer,
                      IssuerSeniority = bond.IssuerSeniority,
                      Maturity = bond.Maturity,
                      CallSchedule = bond.CallSchedule.Select(s => _mapper.Map<CallScheduleItemDto>(s)).ToList(),
                      FixedCouponSchedule = bond.FixedCouponSchedule.Select(s => _mapper.Map<FixedCouponScheduleItemDto>(s)).ToList(),
                      RedemptionSchedule = bond.RedemptionSchedule.Select(s => _mapper.Map<RedemptionScheduleItemDto>(s)).ToList(),
                      PutSchedule = bond.PutSchedule.Select(s => _mapper.Map<PutScheduleItemDto>(s)).ToList(),
                      FloatingSpreadSchedule = bond.FloatingSpreadSchedule.Select(s => _mapper.Map<FloatingSpreadScheduleItemDto>(s)).ToList(),
                  },

                  Price = _mapper.Map<PriceMarketDataDto>(bond.MarketDatas.OfType<PriceMarketData>()
                      .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Date == request.Date && p.AssetId == request.Id)),

                  Rating = _mapper.Map<RatingMarketDataDto>(bond.MarketDatas.OfType<RatingMarketData>()
                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.AssetId == request.Id && x.Date <= request.Date))})

              .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
  ```

What I would like to achieve is 1 database call using ProjectTo<<'BondVm'>>

```
var vm = _context.Bonds
    .Where(x => x.Id == request.Id)
    .ProjectTo<BondVm>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

Here is BondVM just in case:

```
        public class BondVm
        {
            public BondDto BondDto { get; set; }
            public RatingMarketDataDto RatingDto { get; set; }
            public PriceMarketDataDto PriceDto { get; set; }
        }
```

And somehow be able to filter my 2 navigation properties (rating and price) with the conditions above.
I can't figure how to filter my mapping profile with the

Let me know if you need more information. Many thanks for your help!

Edit:

In regards with what Lucian Bargaoanu suggest this is my mapping profile:

```
public BondVmMapper()
            {
                Map.ForMember(d => d.BondDto, o => o.MapFrom(x => x));

                Map.ForMember(d => d.PriceDto, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.MarketDatas.OfType<PriceMarketData>()));

                Map.ForMember(d => d.RatingDto, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.MarketDatas.OfType<RatingMarketData>()));
            }
```

Whats strange about this is that we map a Enumerable on a single object how should this work?

Comment: In your map write `MapFrom` with the filters you need.

Comment: Yes this is what I tried, the problem is I need to filter marketdatas.ofType<RatingMarketData> + I need a Where clause.

Comment: Write that first as an EF LINQ query without AM. If that works you can use it with `ProjectTo`. Inside the `MapFrom` expression you can have a `Where` clause.

Comment: The third option is EF LINQ with just a little bit of AM (but I could easily write it without). My Where clause has parameters who are not in my objet but in my request. How can I pass them to the MapFrom?

Comment: No, I'm saying test it first without AM, just to know what works and can be done with AM. Check the docs about params.